# JS Global Variable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JS file ...

```
  var my_data;

  function getData() {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/aruba?fullText=true',
          type: 'GET',
          async: false,
          success: handleData,
          error: showError
      });
  }

  // Process data returned from AJAX call
  function handleData(data) {
      my_data = data;
      console.log('my_data1', my_data);
  } // end function handleData

  console.log('my_data2', my_data);
  getData(); // Call function
```

When I run this function in console, I get

**my_data2**: undefined

**my_data1**: [{…}] (it returns an array)

I have read a lot about putting `async:false` to fix this issue. But its still not working. Why is *my_data2* not returning an array ?

Comment: you are logging my_data2 before the results of getData() have had a chance to set my_data

Comment: Spot on @monty. Thanks mate. That was it ....

Comment: @Tyler Roper - this is *not* a duplicate. The call to getData() was running synchronously (see async: false in ajax call). He just got the order wrong. I don't have enough cred to vote to reopen apparently,

Comment: @CertainPerformance - this is not a duplicate - see commend above.

Comment: Suffice to say that you should not be using `async: false` to "fix" this problem. Learn about callbacks instead and use them correctly. There is never a reason to make a synchronous "Ajax" call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

swap these:

```
getData(); // Call *sync* function
console.log('my_data2', my_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo are using async: false. But in your case, execution of statement `console.log('my_data2', my_data);` is is done firstly and then execute your ajax function, in that case it return undefined. 
Your code should be like this:

```
  var my_data;

  function getData() {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/aruba?fullText=true',
          type: 'GET',
          async: false,
          success: handleData,
          error: showError
      });
  }

  // Process data returned from AJAX call
  function handleData(data) {
      my_data = data;
      console.log('my_data1', my_data);
  } // end function handleData

  getData(); // Call function
  console.log('my_data2', my_data);
```

it will return array